# Symfony3 + FosUserBundle /login/ instead of /login

Tags: php, symfony, authentication, fosuserbundle

I've been experiencing a strange bug lately. When I want to go to **/login** with the fos_user_security_login route , I'm redirected to  **/login/** .
As a result, I get that message: **No route found for "GET /login/"**

However, if I operate a php bin/console debug:route , I do get that route :

**fos_user_security_login  GET|POST  ANY  ANY  /login**

But, if I go into **@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/security.xml** and that I change the route /login with /login/, it works. There is now way I modify a file in the Vendor folder.

Could somebody explain that extra "/" occurence?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried just adding another route directive to accommodate the trailing slash?  Just duplicate the route for "/login" and add the trailing slash  "/login/"?

Comment: @AaronBelchamber I fixed it, it was just Apache, I restarted it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't look like a Symfony problem but more like Nginx or apache one, you are supposed to get same result with / and without.

Depending of your configurations, I think you should look here : http://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html

Rewrite Rule could help you.

Comment: Thank you !
It was indeed a problem coming from Apache, I restarted it and the problem disappeared.